# Does the volume change under the tensile or compressive stress?

Tags: materials, civil-engineering, stresses

This confusion arise because my teacher says that volume does not change under tensile/compressive stress within the elastic limit of the material ( consider metal here). But as far as I can see via applying Poisson's ratio it does ( otherwise lateral strain would be proportional to square root of longitudinal strain). So does the volume chaneg under tensile stress ? What might be the molecular basis of such?

---

I defined a quantity (cause it was simple to calculate) $ \frac {\Delta A}{A}$ and then found that

via **Poisson's ratio

$$ \frac {\Delta A}{A} = \alpha \epsilon _{lon}( \alpha \epsilon _{lon} +2)$$

whereas the one derived via assuming the volume to be constant (i.e., $AL = A_0 L_0$) was
 $$ \frac {\Delta A}{A} = \frac {\epsilon _{lon}}{\epsilon _{lon} +1}$$

Here $ \alpha = \frac {\epsilon_{lat}}{\epsilon_{lon}}$

Comment: If the length changes under compression for a bar then will the diameter increase?

Comment: @Solar yes it will (Poisson's ratio)

Comment: May I see your equations ?

Comment: So if the length decreases and the diameter increases the net volume change is????

Comment: Relevant: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/266477/the-poisson-ratio-and-conservation-of-volume

Comment: In fact, *Poisson* thought this was correct, and therefore his ratio was 0.5 for all materials. And one of his colleagues Cagniard-Latour *measured* this incorrect value for brass, and so "proved" Poisson was right. Well, everybody makes mistakes sometimes - including your teacher :)

Comment: @SolarMike "the net volume change is????" - either positive, negative, or zero. I'm not sure where you are trying to get to here.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the volume changes.

The relative change of volume $ΔV/V $of a cube due to the stretch of the material :

[image]

Using $V = L^3$ and

$V + \Delta V = (L + \Delta L)\left(L + \Delta L'\right)^2$:

:$\frac{\Delta V}{V} = \left(1 + \frac{\Delta L}{L} \right)\left(1 + \frac{\Delta L'}{L} \right)^2 - 1$

Using the above derived relationship between $\Delta L$ and $\Delta L'$:

:$\frac {\Delta V} {V} = \left(1+\frac{\Delta L}{L} \right)^{1-2\nu} - 1$

and for very small values of $\Delta L \ and \ \Delta L'$, the first-order approximation yields:

$$\frac {\Delta V} {V} \approx (1-2\nu)\frac{\Delta L}{L}$$

For isotropic materials, we can use Lamé parameters

$$ \frac{1}{2} - \frac{E}{6K}$$

where K is bulk modulus and E is elastic modulus or Young's modulus.
[wikipedia link](http://==%20Volumetric%20change%20==%20%20The%20relative%20change%20of%20volume%20''%CE%94V''/''V''%20of%20a%20cube%20due%20to%20the%20stretch%20of%20the%20material%20can%20now%20be%20calculated.%20Using%20%3Cmath%3EV%20=%20L%5E3%3C/math%3E%20and%20%3Cmath%3EV%20+%20%5CDelta%20V%20=%20(L%20+%20%5CDelta%20L)%5Cleft(L%20+%20%5CDelta%20L'%5Cright)%5E2%3C/math%3E:%20%20:%3Cmath%3E%5Cfrac%7B%5CDelta%20V%7D%7BV%7D%20=%20%5Cleft(1%20+%20%5Cfrac%7B%5CDelta%20L%7D%7BL%7D%20%5Cright)%5Cleft(1%20+%20%5Cfrac%7B%5CDelta%20L'%7D%7BL%7D%20%5Cright)%5E2%20-%201%3C/math%3E%20%20Using%20the%20above%20derived%20relationship%20between%20%3Cmath%3E%5CDelta%20L%3C/math%3E%20and%20%3Cmath%3E%5CDelta%20L'%3C/math%3E:%20%20:%3Cmath%3E%5Cfrac%20%7B%5CDelta%20V%7D%20%7BV%7D%20=%20%5Cleft(1+%5Cfrac%7B%5CDelta%20L%7D%7BL%7D%20%5Cright)%5E%7B1-2%5Cnu%7D%20-%201%3C/math%3E%20%20and%20for%20very%20small%20values%20of%20%3Cmath%3E%5CDelta%20L%3C/math%3E%20and%20%3Cmath%3E%5CDelta%20L'%3C/math%3E,%20the%20first-order%20approximation%20yields:%20%20:%3Cmath%3E%5Cfrac%20%7B%5CDelta%20V%7D%20%7BV%7D%20%5Capprox%20(1-2%5Cnu)%5Cfrac%7B%5CDelta%20L%7D%7BL%7D%3C/math%3E%20%20For%20isotropic%20materials%20we%20can%20use%20[[Lam%C3%A9%20parameters%7CLam%C3%A9%E2%80%99s%20relation]]%3Cref%3Ehttps://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1204/1204.3859.pdf%20-%20Limits%20to%20Poisson%E2%80%99s%20ratio%20in%20isotropic%20materials%20%E2%80%93%20general%20result%20for%20arbitrary%20deformation.%3C/ref%3E%20%20:%3Cmath%3E%5Cnu%20%5Capprox%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%20-%20%5Cfrac%7BE%7D%7B6K%7D%3C/math%3E%20%20where%20%3Cmath%3EK%3C/math%3E%20is%20[[bulk%20modulus]]%20and%20%3Cmath%3EE%3C/math%3E%20is%20elastic%20modulus%20(or%20[[Young's%20modulus]]).%20%20Note%20that%20isotropic%20materials%20must%20have%20a%20Poisson's%20ratio%20of%20%3Cmath%3E-1%20%3C%20%5Cnu%20%3C%200.5%3C/math%3E.%20%20Typical%20isotropic%20engineering%20materials%20have%20a%20Poisson's%20ratio%20of%20%3Cmath%3E0.2%20%3C%20%5Cnu%20%3C%200.5%3C/math%3E.%3Cref%20name=%22polymerphysics.net%22)